# Push notifications not working in PWA mobile app with Firebase

Tags: .net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging, blazor-webassembly

I am follow this url https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/firebase-web-push-notifications-26352b136814 for applying the push notification using firebase but it not showing in the PWA application on mobile or browser. it working fine on desktop browser and pwa for desktop application can any one idea about this.

and notification code i am applying on blazor web assembly with .net core 6

can any one having idea about above error if any then guide me so i can do further code for that.